# JPA join query on one-to-many association

Tags: spring-data-jpa, hibernate-onetomany

I have a `one-to-many` relationship with `Customer` and `Order` entity. This is of a composition relationship. I want to write a query to find out if there is a matching `Order` with the given `orderId` and the `customerId`. This method should be in the `CustomerRepository`

```
    @Query("select c from Customer c inner join c.orders o where c.id= ?1 and c.orders.")
    Optional<Customer> findCustomerByOrderId(long orderId, long customerId);
```

I am interested in knowing, if the orderid belongs to the customer. What should be the query and should the method return a count or a boolean from the performance point of view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an Order entity with an id property and customerId property, you can use spring JPA magic and add a method to your OrderRepository (if you have one):

```
boolean existsByIdAndCustomerId(long orderId, long customerId)
```

Performance will be better than getting the customer entity, since it requires less data transfer from the DB to your application.

You can also share more detailed code if this does not answer your question.

Your @Query can be updated as follows to get the customer

```
@Query("select c from Customer c inner join c.orders o where c.id = :customerId and o.id = :orderId")
Optional<Customer> findCustomerByOrderId(long orderId, long customerId);
```

Or if you want to return a count

```
@Query("select count(c) from Customer c inner join c.orders o where c.id = :customerId and o.id = :orderId")
int countCustomerByOrderId(long orderId, long customerId);
```

Comment: I want to write this method inside the `CustomerRepository` and it should be using `@Query` and not DSL

Comment: See updated answer. I'm making some assumptions and hope I don't have typos

Comment: How is this query ```@Query("select count(c) from Customer c inner join Order o on c.id = o.customer.id  and c.id = :customerId and o.id = :orderId")
    int findCustomerByOrderId(long orderId, long customerId);``` different from your query?

Comment: Also, should it be ```Customer c inner join c.orders``` or ```Customer c inner join Orders``` ? Is there any difference?

Comment: There are many ways to skin a cat. It is difficult to say exactly what the best approach is based on what I can see. It all depends on how your entities have been annotated.